# NHibernate Validator and ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, nhibernate-validator

We're looking at upgrading a large-scale project currently implemented using ASP.NET MVC 2 with xVal providing the glue between NHibernate Validator and client-side validation.

When I was looking for resources on using the new "unobtrusive" client side validation used in MVC 3/4 with NHibernate Validator, I was only able to locate a single (and nearly 3 year-old) [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2010/07/20/nhibernate-client-validator-asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx) about this.

Has anyone successfully used NHibernate Validator for client-side validation in MVC 3/4? If so, what has your experience been?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I don't have any experience directly with NHibernate, [FluentValidation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) (a validation framework worth considering itself) has an [MVC 3/4 adapter extension](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/8aacd3be1ad2ced2be247a2a8874aa079751387a#src/FluentValidation.Mvc3/FluentValidationModelMetadataProvider.cs) project which would serve as an excellent guide to creating an NHibernate Validator implementation.

Answer (score 0):

So, i've never used NHibernate Validator, but consider to, because NHibernate Validator has a better perfomance than native MVC unobtrusive validator(MVC validator is totaly based on reflection, in case of NHibernate Validator reflection work happens at startup only).
In case of a large-scale project, i think it is better way.